# How to trim a text in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trim a text which  has a structure like that;

```
base_text = Surname, Name (ID)

desired_text = Name
```

Could you please help me for how can I do that ?

Regards

Comment: is the "," always a part of the base_text?

Comment: Yes "," and "(ID)" always the part of base_text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MyAnswer()
    Dim oCell As Range
    For Each oCell In Range("A1:A100")
        If oCell <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, oCell, ", ") <> 0 Then
                If InStr(1, oCell, " (") <> 0 Then
                    oCell = Right(oCell, Len(oCell) - InStr(1, oCell, ",") - 1)
                    oCell = Left(oCell, InStr(1, oCell, " (") - 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here we loop through each cell in `A1:A100` range.
`Left` and `Right` return given number of symbols from a string.
`InStr` returns the position of a symbol in current string.
`Len` returns number of symbols in a given string.

Comment: Thank you for you support i will try your code but there's no range and cell value in fact. I'll using the code for the "Application.UserName" feature.

Comment: @Hakan You can store `Application.UserName` in string variable first and modify it the same way `Name = Right(...) : Name = Left(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. text function like
   left, right, mid
2. split function where " " (space) or "," is delimiter

Answer (score 0):

as a formula you can use this, assuming `Base_text` is in `A1` :

`=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1)),FIND("(",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1)))-1)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved using regular expressions. This will output the 'Name' in the cell next to your original data. It can be also be easily manipulated to get all text parts of the string. The range will need to be updated to match yours

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c

    ' Update this line with your Range
    Set rng = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "[a-z]+"

        For Each c In rng
            If .test(c.Value2) Then
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = .Execute(c.Value2)(1)
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using the split function**

(See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)

Using the `Split` function you can split a string into substrings based on a given delimiter. There results a zero based 1-dim substring array whose items can be referenced by their index number.

i) So you will get the second substring using index 1:

```
sName = split(base_text, ",")(1)
```

ii) As you want to extract only the name and not the id in brackets, you have to execute another split on this result, now indexing the first substring (index 0) and remove spaces via the `Trim` function:

```
  sName = Trim(Split(sName, "(")(0))
```

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetNameToken()
  Dim base_text As String
  Dim sName     As String
' base_text = Application.UserName      ' << actual code
  base_text = "Surname, Name (ID)"      ' << pattern example

' i) get substring right of the colon delimiter (index 1)
  sName = Split(base_text & ",", ",")(1)
' ii) get substring left of the bracket delimiter (index 0)
  sName = Trim(Split(sName & " ", "(")(0))

  MsgBox "UserName = """ & base_text & """" & vbNewLine & _
         "=> """ & sName & """"
End Sub
```

**Notes**

i) In order to avoid a possible index out of order error in case of a base text with other delimiters, I used a trick: I concatenated a fictional colon delimiter to the text to be split (this would result in an empty 2nd substring, if there were no colon delimiter in the original text):

`sName = Split(base_text & ",", ",")(1)`

ii) In the second split you need an additional string concatenation only in case of sName = "", otherwise you would try split an empty string.

*Additional hint*

You can get the upper index of the resulting split array items via the `UBound` function, e.g. `n = UBound(Split("one two three"," "))`, in this example `2` (=three items indexed 0, 1, 2).